# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to \pi /2}(\sin x)^{\tan x}$

Tags: limits

I want to evaluate: $$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}(\sin x)^{\tan x}$$

My solution is reached by L'Hospital's rule.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \pi/2}{(\sin x)^{\tan x}}&=[1^{\infty}] = ((\sin x)^{\tan x})' \\ 
&= {e}^{\tan x\ln\sin x}\cdot({\tan x\ln\sin x)'} \\&={e}^{\tan x\ln\sin x}\cdot\frac{\ln\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}+\frac{\tan x\cos x}{\sin x}
\end{align}

My questions are: the fraction $\frac{\ln\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}$ results in $\frac{0}{0}$ or rather just $0$? T.i. first two expressions $e^{\tan x\ln\sin x}$ and $\frac{\ln\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}$ still results in indeterminate forms, can I just ignore them and assume that limit is $1$ ( because of $\frac{\tan x\cos x}{\sin x}$)?

Comment: Do you mean to write $$\lim\limits_{x\to \pi /2 } (\sin x)^{\tan x} = \color{blue}{\lim\limits_{x\to \pi /2}} ((\sin x)^{\tan x})' ?$$

Answer (score 1):

No! the first step is $1^\infty$ form. So we begin with $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \log (\sin x ^{\tan x})=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\log (\sin x )}{\cot x}$$ Now  it is $\frac{0}{0}$ form, so apply L'Hospital rule to this and finish your problem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply L'Hopitals rule directly as it is not of the form $\frac00$ as you seem to think. We need the limit to be of the form $\frac00$ or $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$ in order to apply L'Hopitals rule. Firstly we can make use of $x=e^{\ln{(x)}}$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}(\sin{(x)})^{\tan{(x)}}=\exp{\left(\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\left(\tan{(x)}\ln{(\sin{(x)})}\right)\right)}$$
then we have the limit 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}(\tan{(x)}\ln{(\sin{(x)})})
&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\left(\frac{\ln{(\sin{(x)})}}{\cot{(x)}}\right)\\
&=^{\text{L'Hopitals } \frac00}\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\left(\frac{\tan{(x)}}{-\csc^2{(x)}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}(-\frac{\sin^3{(x)}}{\cos{(x)}})\\
&=0\\
\end{align}$$
So the final answer is given by
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}(\sin{(x)})^{\tan{(x)}}=\exp{\left(\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\left(\tan{(x)}\ln{(\sin{(x)})}\right)\right)}=\exp{(0)}=1$$